# Mapping values of matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing, mapping, coordinates, indices

Assume I have a matrix called A.
The values of the matrix represent coordinates,
so row 2 and column 3 is the coordinate (2,3) in the 2D plan.

How can I map all the values of the matrix to different indices so that `(0,0)` would get the mapping value of 0 etc.?

```
(0,0) -> 0
(0,1) -> 1
(0,2) ->2
..
..
```

and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: MATLAB doesn't have `0` as index.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are okay with the MATLAB indexing that starts with 1, this would work -

```
A1 = reshape([1:numel(A)],size(A,1),[])'
```

If you would like to start the mapping from `0`, just subtract `1` -

```
A1 = reshape([1:numel(A)],size(A,1),[])' -1
```

Answer (score 1):

> "The `sub2ind` command determines the equivalent single index corresponding to a set of subscript values."

For example, if

```
i = sub2ind(size(A), 2, 3);
```

then

`A(2,3)` and `A(i)` refer to the same element in a matrix `A`.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB you can [index matrices linearly](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511). Suppose you have the matrix:

```
a =    
   16    2    3   13
    5   11   10    8
    9    7    6   12
    4   14   15    1
```

Now, you can access the element in position `(3,2)` either using normal subscripts, or using the linear equivalent.

```
a(3,2)
ans = 7

a(7)
ans = 7
```

Assuming you have your indices as a list from 1 to `numel(a)` and don't really need a link between `(3,2)` and `(7)`, this would be the simplest way to do it.

As you state, you want the element in position `(0,0)` to have index `(0)`. Since MATLAB indexing starts at `1` you have two alternatives:

If you get a list (for instance from another program) where elements are listed from zero to `(numel(a) - 1)`, such as `ind = [0, 3, 6, 8]`, my suggestion is you simply do `ind = ind + 1` (or `ind_1 = ind + 1` if you don't want to overwrite the original vector.

Otherwise you can add one every time this way: `x = a(ind + 1);`.

However, if you really want a link between `(3,2)` and `(7)`, I believe [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) is the way to go.